Blower motor not coming on in cool mode
sorry for my lack of expertise or if I'm posting this incorrectly :( our home air conditioning is having problems, the blower motor seems to not come on when on cool mode. If we have the thermostat on heat or just with fan on then the motor inside will come on but when turned to cool it doesn't, the outside compressor comes on and the condenser unit gets cold but the blower motor won't come on. I've checked the leads on the PCB and the blower motor is getting 120 volts from the live and neutral and then when I check the COM to COOL on the PCB it's getting 24volts as expected. Currently the blue wire from the blower motor (labeled as HEAT/3 on the diagram) is what's connected to the COOL lead on the PCB which I find odd, the other wires that don't match up as expected would be a yellow (labeled as SPARE/4) going to the HEAT lead on the PCB and the black wire (labeled as COOL/5) going to the SPARE 1 lead on the PCB. My question is, if the blower motor is already not working properly, would changing these wires to get it to work until we can replace it be a terrible idea? It seems odd to me that what is the less powerful fan setting is set to cool. I'm in Texas where it can get to 85+ degrees in the house and am not very well equipped with funds to pay someone to fix this so any help is appreciated
(edited)
I'm not too sure on the model #s, I think the PCB is cepl130934-01 by Carrier and then the thermostat is the t2-pac01 by Bryant I believe
Pictures are here for better resolution: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1gu4U5-IA58CwbzYsZe8vFOhyKS86fnGs
Diagram:

PCB:

Thermostat wiring:

PCB wires:

I unplugged these two and checked the voltage with the ac turned on to find it was indeed sending 24 volts to the correct lead:


I know the wires were probably intentionally set that way, I'm mainly wondering if anything else other than the blower motor can be damaged from changing the motor speed to an even higher one when in the cool setting

Some things that can help an answer: Model# of the furnace and thermostat. Pictures of the wiring inside the furnace and the wiring screws at the thermostat.

also a good clear copy of the wiring diagram.  If you're referring to specific points on it, put arrows on it and photos of the wiring.  Your description is detailed (good) but hard to follow without the visual aids (bad).  Also:  was it working properly before?  Did anyone change anything or anything happen to it?

@Triplefault Hello thank you for the reply! I'm not too sure on the model #s, I think the PCB is cepl130934-01 by Carrier and then the thermostat is the t2-pac01 by Bryant I believe, I included some pictures to help!

@MadMonty Hello thank you! I included some pictures to help, It's been worked on throughout the years but not too recently, the cool function stopped working last summer

It sounds like the controller is doing its job.  What we don't know is whether the motor is bad or the wiring bad (either defective or miswired).  Your report that the spares are in use implies that someone may have thought a wire or two was bad and substituted a spare.
Steps:

Power OFF.  Look at the motor end to see if splices have been made or terminals swapped around on the plug or socket (if it has them).  If so, they should match the PCB end.  If they don't, correct them.
Power OFF.  Verify that the right motor leads have continuity to the right PCB terminals with a multimeter.  If not, substitute a spare (or make your own temporary, splicing it with wire nuts).  If the motor has a plug and socket, measure on the motor side to rule out a connector defect.
Power ON.  Verify that the motor is receiving 120V between L and N, and 24V between C and 5.    If the motor has a plug and socket, measure on the motor side to rule out a connector defect.

If all this is in order, the motor is bad.  Since it works in heat mode, you have a workaround:  yes, with Power OFF, you can swap 3 (or 1 if Fan Only mode works) with 5 at the PCB without damaging the PCB board.  The swapped function will no longer work, so you will want that new motor.
